# Masking client secrets in .net

Tags: .net, powerbi, azure-keyvault, secret-key

For my .net application. Thre are some powerbi values like application id and client secret. But to be on safe side they should be in azure key vault. What would be the workaround for this one? When I try code scan with Fortify it shows asp.net mis configuration and MIME sniffing

Comment: What do you mean "the workaround"? You described something you'd like to do, then described two problems that some scanning tool found that don't seem to be related to client secrets or Azure Key Vault. Please clearly explain the issue, explain how those connect, and show relevant config/code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this by storing these values in Key Vault:

1. Host your ASP.NET application in Azure and using a Managed Identity to retrieve the values (most secure)
2. Host your ASP.NEt application not in Azure and use an application id/certificate with non-exportable private key to retrieve the values (still secure).